# trying to enqueue script in wordpress

Tags: javascript

I've read the codex section on wp-enqeue, but am still struggling.

Basically, I would like to get the following to display properly in my theme's widget area (on every page):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/wp-content/uploads/social_counter/css/styles.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/wp-content/uploads/social_counter/css/tipTip.css" />

<div id="social_counter">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/wp-content/uploads/social_counter/js/jquery.tipTip.minified.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/wp-content/uploads/social_counter/js/social_counter.js"></script>
</div>
```

I created a text widget into which I pasted the code, but it breaks a few things in the template as there is likely a conflict since jquery is already loaded by the theme and/ or other plugins.

Could someone show me how to best form this using wp_enqueue, and where to paste the subsequent code (functions.php of theme?)?

Thanks.

I've tried the following:

```
if(!is_admin()){
wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );
wp_register_script( 'jquery', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js');
wp_enqueue_script('custom_script',get_bloginfo('wpurl').'/wp-content/uploads/social_counter/js/jquery.tipTip.minified.js',false);
wp_enqueue_script('custom_script',get_bloginfo('wpurl').'/wp-content/uploads/social_counter/js/social_counter.js',array('jquery'),'1.4.2',false);
}
```

It seem to load two of the scripts when I view the page source, but not the google jquery, and the content does not show...

now i have the following, still nothing (two scripts show up, but not the google jquery):

```
wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );
wp_register_script( 'jquery', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js');
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
wp_enqueue_script('custom_script',get_bloginfo('wpurl').'/wp-content/uploads/social_counter/js/jquery.tipTip.minified.js',false);
wp_enqueue_script('custom_script',get_bloginfo('wpurl').'/wp-content/uploads/social_counter/js/social_counter.js',array('jquery'),'1.4.2',false);
```

Latest Edit.. (i really wish stack overflow would adopt a mroe user-friendly threading system :/ )

```
function add_scripts(){
// Load jQuery
if ( !is_admin() ) {
   wp_deregister_script('jquery');
   wp_register_script('jquery', ("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"), false);
   wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
}
// Your Scripts
wp_enqueue_script('custom_script',get_bloginfo('wpurl').'/wp-content/uploads/social_counter/js/jquery.tipTip.minified.js',false);
wp_enqueue_script('custom_script',get_bloginfo('wpurl').'/wp-content/uploads/social_counter/js/social_counter.js',array('jquery'),'1.4.2',false);
}
add_action('init','add_scripts');
```

Comment: Is it worked???

Comment: no, for some reason, i'm sure i'm messing up. it does seem to laod the scripts, but the actual content does not appear..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually don't need to worry about conflicting with the admin pages anymore. There is a "wp_enqueue_scripts" hook that makes sure the scripts aren't called on admin pages.

From WP Codex:

```
<?php
function my_scripts_method() {
  wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );
  wp_register_script( 'jquery',    'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6/jquery.min.js');
  wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
}    

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method');
?>
```

But if you need a custom jQuery core (or add-on) for the admin pages, you'll need to use the "init" hook with the !admin conditional.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at this link:

[5-tips-for-using-jquery-with-wordpress](http://www.ericmmartin.com/5-tips-for-using-jquery-with-wordpress/)

You can add the scripts by calling a function in **functions.php**.

Here is an example how to do this:

```
function add_scripts(){
        wp_register_script('scriptName', 'Path to the script'); //Register script
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery'); 
        wp_enqueue_script('scriptName'); //adding script

    }
    add_action('init','add_scripts'); //calling function in init
```

Also this [link](http://weblogtoolscollection.com/archives/2010/05/06/adding-scripts-properly-to-wordpress-part-1-wp_enqueue_script/) will be helpful.

**EDIT:**

Try this one

```
function add_scripts(){
// Load jQuery
if ( !is_admin() ) {
   wp_register_script('jquery', ("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"), false);
   wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
}
// Your Scripts
wp_register_script('script1', get_bloginfo('url').'/wp-content/uploads/social_counter/js/jquery.tipTip.minified.js');
wp_register_script('script2',get_bloginfo('url').'/wp-content/uploads/social_counter/js/social_counter.js',array('jquery'),'1.4.2',false);
wp_enqueue_script('script1');
wp_enqueue_script('script2');
}
add_action('init','add_scripts');
```

Comment: @Dijo David please see my revisions

Comment: @vulgarbulgar you have not used wp_enqueue_script('jquery');

Comment: @vulgarbulgar How u calling the function in functions.php? I have edited and add 1 more ink for reference.

Comment: @Dijo David Edited. see revisions above

Comment: @vulgarbar is_admin() is checking whether the current page is admin panel or dashboard. So there will be no conflict when you are in admin panel. How u calling this code? Put all the code inside a function and call the function in init. Its worked for me..

Comment: http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags#The_Administration_Panels

Comment: @Dijo David see latest edit

Answer (score 1):

Best place is in your **functions.php**.

**Example:**

```
wp_enqueue_script("name", ("path/to/file"), false);
```

The false array will enqueue the script into the header, where you define `wp_header();` - If you set it to true, it will enqueue the script into your footer where you define `wp_footer();`

**Edit**:

```
wp_enqueue_script('yourscriptname', get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory') . '/js/jsyourscript.js');
```

In your revised post you have this code

```
if(!is_admin()){
wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );
wp_register_script( 'jquery', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js');
wp_enqueue_script('custom_script',get_bloginfo('wpurl').'/wp-content/uploads/social_counter/js/jquery.tipTip.minified.js',false);
wp_enqueue_script('custom_script',get_bloginfo('wpurl').'/wp-content/uploads/social_counter/js/social_counter.js',array('jquery'),'1.4.2',false);
}
```

Please notice that you've placed the 2 scripts you wish to *enqueue* **inside** the conditional statement that if **not** admin - *do this* -

This may be the reason it's not appearing to work for you.

**Edit 2**

```
// Load jQuery
if ( !is_admin() ) {
   wp_deregister_script('jquery');
   wp_register_script('jquery', ("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"), false);
   wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
}
// Your Scripts
wp_enqueue_script('custom_script',get_bloginfo('wpurl').'/wp-content/uploads/social_counter/js/jquery.tipTip.minified.js',false);
wp_enqueue_script('custom_script2',get_bloginfo('wpurl').'/wp-content/uploads/social_counter/js/social_counter.js',array('jquery'),'1.4.2',false);
```

Cleaned it up a little, put the jquery back into the conditional statement also put false onto it.

Also each new script you enqueue has to have a **unique name**. Both of yours are called **custom_script**

Comment: @vulgarbulgar Hmm, I'm not sure what supposedly wrong right now, nothing in the Edit 2 is wrong. What's currently not working?

Comment: @tfbox http://demo.tutorialzine.com/2010/05/showing-facebook-twitter-rss-stats-jquery-yql/demo.html - just trying to include this essentially, inside a widget area. testing on a page for now until i get it working at all.

Comment: @vulgarbulgar - I like it, looks good. So what's not working currently via wordpress?

Comment: @tfbox haha, thats not mine- thats the demo version :) i would like that to work in my wp